# How to paging the folders and files in swift object storage?

Tags: api, openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, openstack-swift, object-storage

I used the query parameters 'limit', 'marker', and 'end_marker'.
The parameter limit with marker works well(ex ?limit=10&marker=image.png) but when I try to use 'end_marker' to retrieve the previous page(ex ?limit=10&end_marker=image.png), it doesn't work well.
How can I get the previous page in swift object storage?

I referred http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#storage_object_services

Answer (score 0):

The "end_marker" takes in account from the first object, I think, you should try without limit.

Answer (score 0):

marker = the file you want to START from

end_marker = the file you want to STOP at

```
?limit=10&marker=image.png
```

Means you are going to start at image.png, and get 10 results.

```
?limit=10&end_marker=image.png
```

Means you are going to start at the first file, get up to 10 results, or until you get to image.png.

If you want to go to the previous page, you will need to change the marker file.